# Triggering iOS build/test job via Github pull request on CloudBees

Tags: cloudbees

I would like Jenkins to comment whether a merge passes or fails (much like Travis CI) on  Github pull requests. I understand this is a feature on [BuildHive](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/BuildHive). However, I cannot find an option on BuildHive for using [customer provided slaves](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Customer+Provided+Slaves). My question is twofold:

1. Is there an option to limit builds to customer provided slaves on BuildHive?
2. Is there a way I could enable comments on pull requests using DEV@cloud (the actual job must be run on a customer provided slave)? If so, could you point me in the right direction to get this set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DEV@cloud can validate pull request as BuildHive does, with some additional configuration. See http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Github+Pull+Request+Validation

Answer (score 1):

Answering in the order of your questions:

1. BuildHive uses the Validated Merge plugin for Git from Jenkins Enterprise to enable Jenkins to perform pull requests and run the builds before doing a push to the main repo. That said, currently you cannot use Customer Provided Executors with BuildHive.
2. DEV@cloud: Normally, all Jenkins Enterprise plugins are available in a paid tier of DEV@cloud. However, this plugin is not - as the plugin sets up a git server within Jenkins - not easily achievable in a cloud setup. I have created a [ticket](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/tickets/5091) on CloudBees support requesting that the plugin be made available and the engineering team will investigate into delivering the feature.

Meanwhile, if you like you can use [Jenkins Enterprise](http://www-staging.cloudbees.com/jenkins-enterprise-by-cloudbees-download.cb) to use the feature (however it is an on-premises solution).

Comment: I don't have permissions to see your ticket, but thanks! I can't find any information explicitly stating Jenkins Enterprise handles commenting on pull requests, though. Can you link me to more information?

Comment: Seems like it is easier than I thought - Refer Nicolas' article that he wrote up in response to the question. His answer supersedes mine.